# Adding descriptions to meta data in PHP and .tpl

Tags: php, meta-tags

I am new to PHP programming, and I have a site that needs some SEO.  It is a PHP site, and the files are .tpl.  For its description, it has

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
```

How can I hard code the descriptions and keywords without breaking the PHP?

Comment: Set `$description = "Whatever you want";`?

Comment: The tag description is correctly, but what is your administration system? We can not know what the variable $description contains.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be appropriate to work with an array containing your Meta information.

```
$meta = array();
$meta["description"] = 'My site';

foreach($meta as $key => $value)
{
    echo '<meta name="'.$key.'" content="'.$value.'"/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the $description (and whatever variables you like in a .php file before you include the template.
For example:

```
$description = 'My site';
$keywords = 'my, site';

// the code to include the template
```